# NSWindow in front of all apps + ignores space/fullscreen transitions

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

I'm working on an application for "fading out" a screen to hide the weird OS X full screen transition. In 10.7, I was able to do this by creating an NSWindow and using setCollectionBehavior to force it to float above everything else:

```
[window setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorStationary | NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces | NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary];
```

My app launches, fades to black, then waits for a signal from the other app before fading out and showing the content underneath. However, in 10.8, it covers the screen, shows the transition moment when the app underneath goes full screen, then pops back in front of the app.

Any ideas on how to push this app in front of these obnoxious transitions?

Comment: I should note: I am running the app as an agent, which does seem to place across all spaces... Just not above fullscreen apps _when they're transitioning_.

Comment: OK! SO this isn't an _answer_ per se, but here's a thing that can work:

[Quartz Fade Effects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/QuartzDisplayServicesConceptual/Articles/FadeEffects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004232)

This allows you to fade out your main display, which supersedes everything else. If you don't capture the main display with `CGDisplayCapture (kCGDirectMainDisplay);`, the other app will "pop" into the foreground after it goes fullscreen. 

Leaving the question open in case someone can really answer it, but this is OK for me...

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? My goal is to open a window so from desktop 1, while user is focused on desktop2 (due to full screen app), and i want that window to float over all desktops.